# Get resources id from a string

Tags: android, android-resources

How can I do something like this?

```
for(String name: nameArray){    
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);   
// the line below does not work of course 
    i.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.name);
//do some stuff
}
```

I've searched up some solutions but most of them involves integer IDs which I do not have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check the code below?

I'm not totally sure if it works.. However, I know that you can use `Resources.getIdentifier()` which returns the ID. However, I'm not sure if it works with `drawable` as well.

```
for(String name: nameArray){    
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setBackgroundImage(getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

Comment: This should work, yes, however, something may want to be done with that ImageView, otherwise only the last drawable will be shown